# How to change an APK file package name, either using a PC or an Android device?

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, package-name

### Background

As we all know the package-name of an app is like its ID to the world. however, some apps/devices use it sometimes for "dirty" tricks.

as an example, some devices are cheating on benchmarks by looking at which app is curently on the foreground (link [**here**](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7384/)).

### the question

suppose i have an apk file, even one that wasn't made by me, how can i change its app's package name?

is it even possible? i mean, changing the package name of an app might surely cause some problems , even when opening activities...

I wonder if it's possible to do so either on a PC or an Android device (or both, even with root permission if needed).

I've heard [**APK-tool**](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) can help with this, but couldn't find out how.

note: i don't mind that the process would create a new APK instead of modifying the original app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a app called apk editor that you can use to (obviously) edit apks, just select the apk and press "common edit" or something along those lines and you can change the package name from there. dont make *waaaay* too many changes as the apk may stop working.

Answer (score 0):

My experience on creating numerous benchmarks is that apk files are known by the project names when first created and renaming the apk file makes no difference. Given Eclipse project files, a recompilation with a different ID can be arranged by changing several labels and file names. I have to do this now as my upgraded Eclipse does not accept my standard template.

Comment: have you read the article? that's how they've found out that the devices cheat. they did it for multiple benchmarks apps, and they didn't really have their code. it was enough to change the package name. anyway, this is only one example. i think it can be useful for other cases that i haven't thought of.